# Event Based Break Point

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug, breakpoints

Using Xdebug and PhpStorm (or any other debugging tool/IDE) is there any way to define a condition to break the execution without specifying the breakpoint's **line**?

For example "break when `$x>4`, in a file that it has a variable named `$x`, or break when `$foo->bar()` returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet possible in PhpStorm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-7992